# Show dates for flot chart

Tags: php, flot

I'm trying to graph some data with flot on a php page. I can graph the points without issue, but am having some issues showing the date under the graph. The scale is a week, samples a minute at a time, so a daily marker would be sufficient.

I'm reading the data from a database, and the data is being put in the following format:

`$io_read`

`[ [1411499810000, 100], [1411499921000, 110] ]`

during the read from the table, the timestamp is being converted to the Java timestamp:

`$timest = ($row['Local Epoch']) * 1000;`

Here's the PHP code to display the graph:

```
    echo "<h2>Total IOs</h2>";`
    echo "<div id='placeholder-io'></div>";`
    // IO line graph`
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo "$(document).ready(function () {";
    echo "var d1 = $io_read";
    echo "var d2 = $io_write";
    echo "var iodata = [ {label: \"Reads\", data: d1}, {label: \"Writes\", data: d2} ];";
    echo "$.plot($(\"#placeholder-io\"), iodata);";
    echo "});";
    echo "</script>";
```

I've tried this:

```
    echo "var options = [ xaxis: { mode: \"time\", timeformat: \"%m/%d\" } ]; ";
    echo "$.plot($(\"#placeholder-io\"), iodata, options);";
```

But that failed to renfer a graph.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors - if I add the dates like I show above, it does not create the chart at all.

Comment: Can you build a [Code snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) etc. which shows your problem using the output from your php script?

Comment: Strangely enough, it worked in jfiddle. I did some more troubleshooting on my end and ended up calling jquery.flot.js from the project page which also started to work. I replaced my local copy of jquery.flot.js and all seems well now.